# VSCode pytest discovery not working: conda error?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I'm having a strange problem with VSCode's python testing functionality. When I try to discover tests I get the following error:

```
> conda run -n sandbox --no-capture-output python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/pythonFiles/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir . -s --cache-clear .
cwd: .
[ERROR 2022-1-3 21:49:47.851]: Error discovering pytest tests:
 [r [Error]: 
EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: /Users/david.hoffman/miniconda3/envs/sandbox/envs/sandbox
```

But obviously there's a duplication error: `/Users/david.hoffman/miniconda3/envs/sandbox/envs/sandbox`.

If I run this command directly in the terminal I get the expected output and no errors:

```
conda run -n sandbox --no-capture-output python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/pythonFiles/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir . -s --cache-clear
```

I'm completely stumped as there doesn't seem to be any settings that would affect this.

I tried reinstalling VSCode from scratch (after removing all the local files) same with conda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways I've found to fix:

1. Change the name of the `conda` environment. Just cloning `sandbox` to `boxsand` did the trick
2. Add `python.condaPath` variable to VSCode's preferences

Comment: how should you set the `condaPath` variable in the settings?

Comment: got it: sthg like `~/miniconda3/bin/conda`, and just using that solved the problem for me. It indeed seems that it's because the python extension is confused between the base conda and the conda installed in the environment as mentioned in @JinjerJohn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72666448/4332585).

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, I ran into the same issue but found a different (easier?) solution.

Turns out I had `conda` installed *within* the conda environment. Uninstalling conda *from the environment itself* (`mamba uninstall -n myenv conda`) fixed it.

Lots of people have run into this, though, and there are active issues in both the [VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18493) and [conda](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11174) Githubs.

Comment: Removing conda from within the environment solved the problem for me. But mamba relies on it being installed, so I have yet to set up an environment that has both mamba installed and works for VS Code tests. Did that work for you?